# hive on tez, cannot monitor timeline in Tez UI

Tags: hive, hadoop-yarn, directed-acyclic-graphs, tez

I configured hive on tez as following.
I can see my queries in HiveServer2 Web UI.
But, I cannot see DAGs in Tez UI after I submit hive queries.
What configurations am I missing?

- $HADOOP/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml

  - mapreduce.framework.name=yarn-tez
- $YARN/conf/yarn-site.xml

  - yarn.timeline-service.enabled=true
  - yarn.timeline-service.hostname=localhost
  - yarn.timeline-service.http-cross-origin.enabled=true
  - yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled=true
- $HIVE/conf/hive-site.xml

  - hive.execution.engine=tez
- $TEZ/conf/tez-site.xml

  - tez.history.logging.service.class=
    org.apache.tez.dag.history.logging.ats.ATSHistoryLoggingService
  - tez.tez-ui.history-url.base=http://localhost/tez-ui/

I tried simple select query, and join query.
The join query got this errors.

```
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:380)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:257)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.access$800(SQLOperation.java:91)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork$1.run(SQLOperation.java:348)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation$BackgroundWork.run(SQLOperation.java:362)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:296)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:291)
at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.executeSql(JDBCInterpreter.java:581)
at org.apache.zeppelin.jdbc.JDBCInterpreter.interpret(JDBCInterpreter.java:692)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:97)
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:498)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What query are you executing? can you please give example?

Comment: @Shubhangi Any queries. For example, 'select * from mytable limit 10;'

Comment: "select * from table" kind of query may not create any job. That is correct behavior. Do you see issue for other queries such as "select col1, col2 from table where col3='xyz'" kind of queries ?

Comment: @Shubhangi I updated my question.